# Error in Morphing Vertices using JSON Loader

Tags: javascript, json, morphing

I've read other articles about morphing vertices, particularly my other post. Then I came up with this code, but still there are errors and I can't find the answer to my current problem.

I've read this example on  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js and used the codes there. Yet there are still problems that I can't even know what seems the problem.

Code:

```
<script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
  var camera, scene, renderer;
  var geometry, material, mesh, loader;

  //decalaration of javascript variables thru PHP Declaration
  var customHeight = "<?php $height = ($_POST['height'])*20; print $height; ?>";
  var customWidth = "<?php $width = ($_POST['width'])*20; print $width; ?>";

    var init = function() {
      //camera
     camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 10000 );
     camera.position.z = 1000;
     //scene
     scene = new THREE.Scene();
     //renderer
     renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
     renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
     renderer.setClearColor(0x404040 , 10);

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    customHeightWidth(customWidth, customHeight);

      function customHeightWidth(width, height){

    //loader
        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    //material
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    overdraw: false,
    morphTargets: true,
    wireframe: true
    });
//loader function
loader = function ( showStatus ) {
THREE.Loader.call( this, showStatus );
this.withCredentials = false;
};
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.load = function ( url, callback, texturePath ) {
var scope = this;
// todo: unify load API to for easier SceneLoader use
texturePath = texturePath && ( typeof texturePath === "string" ) ? texturePath : this.extractUrlBase( url );
this.onLoadStart();
this.loadAjaxJSON( this, url, callback, texturePath );
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var json = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.parse = function ( json, texturePath ) {

var scope = this,
geometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
scale = ( json.scale !== undefined ) ? 1.0 / json.scale : 1.0;
parseMorphing( scale );

function parseMorphing( scale ) {
  if ( json.morphTargets !== undefined ) {
     var i, l, v, vl, dstVertices, srcVertices;
     for ( i = 0, l = json.morphTargets.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
       geometry.morphTargets[ i ] = {};
       geometry.morphTargets[ i ].name = json.morphTargets[ i ].name;
           geometry.morphTargets[ i ].vertices = [];

    dstVertices = geometry.morphTargets[ i ].vertices;
    srcVertices = json.morphTargets [ i ].vertices;

    for( v = 0, vl = srcVertices.length; v < vl; v += 3 ) {
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    vertex.x = srcVertices[ v ] * scale;
    vertex.y = srcVertices[ v + 1 ] * scale;
    vertex.z = srcVertices[ v + 2 ] * scale;

    dstVertices.push( vertex );
    }
      }

   }

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
   scene.add( mesh );

     }
   };

    var animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    //mesh.rotation.x += 0.01; 
    //mesh.rotation.y -= 0.05;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
     }

 init();
 animate();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing like what you were trying to do before. Now it looks like you are trying to parse a JSON file directly, in which you should be now referencing http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse

I see loads of problems in this script. You should refer to the source code of that link because there isn't much there and it pretty straight forward.

The block I shared with you before won't work on its own. It was simply an example of how you populate the geometry.morphTargets, you still have other things to do like setup MorphAnimation class (which the source code of the link demonstrates)

Comment: I understand most of the codes to link you've given, but there is one thing that I didn't understand so well. `loader.load( "models/animated/horse.js", function( geometry ) {` this `models/animated/horse.js` is this a geometric figure you've created in another js file?

Comment: I did not create it, but you could create a similar JSON file using the Blender exporter.

Comment: your first example seemed like you were trying to define the vertices manually, in that case what I may recommend is to build a JSON object (formatted like one that would result from opening one of those files) and then passing the JSON object to loader.parse() and letting the JSONLoader class do all the work of sorting the data for you. This would be far less painful than copying code from the class and trying to reconstruct it on your own.

Comment: Can you direct me on a site where I can further study those kind of examples? I got a little confused on what am I going to do next.

Comment: Can you please refer to this updated codes? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014514/vertice-morphing-using-json-three-js